# GET условие

Tags: php

Как составить условие (if) на данный GET запрос, помогите 
highlights-studio.ru/highlight.php?watch=1?action=delete&id=1

Comment: highlights-studio.ru/highlight.php?watch=1&action=delete&id=1
чуть поправил запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_GET['watch'] == 1) { /* some code */ }
if ($_GET['action'] == 'delete') { /* some code */ }
if ($_GET['id'] == 1) { /* some code */ }
```

так, не?